# What GIT / workflow do I use to avoid overwriting my server side Django users, with my local users who are dummy/test users?

Tags: python, django, git, sqlite, github

I am developing a Django application in Atom locally, and then on pythonanywhere, when I'm ready, I'm doing a GIT PUSH command after syncing those changes to GITHUB. The problem is, at some point, those changes which were pushed through from my local development env have overwritten all my live users with *just* the local dummy users I've been using for testing and development.

Basically, I'm testing the login and registration system locally, logging in and registering with lots of dumb emails. Once I was happy it was working, I synced the Django code I'd changed to GITHUB (with the desktop app) and then did a GIT PUSH command on a PythonAnywhere (my server) console. The sqlite DB is included in those updates/sync - is that correct? Or should it just be totally ignored?

I just realised, that one (perhaps all?) pushes have overwritten my sqlite DB, and there were perhaps 30 or so actual users who had signed up on the website whose data is no longer registered on the site. I managed to find a trace of them in the Django Admin logs, and I've found the version history of the Sqlite DB on GITHUB, but my question is - how do I avoid this happening?

What is the workflow to avoid this situation in the future? And is there a command I can run in shell to get those users back into my 'live' database from the backedup SQlite file?

I know this is a simple question, but I'm new to development and I'm slowly getting there with troubleshooting the code, but versioning, GIT, and workflow are tricky things to get my head around.

Comment: I should say - when I did my GIT PUSH (and started to push the site live) via a terminal, GIT told me something about 'docking' changes? Like, before I could push the changes, it forced me to do a command before I could do that. I did as I was told then pushed the changes - is this where I've gone wrong?

Comment: It was GIT STASH. This is what I was asked to do. Update - the data from my users is not in any versions of my database which I went and looked through on GITHUB.

Comment: You don't commit your database to your repository. You shouldn't even use sqlite in production.

Comment: You should have ignored the sqlite database completely. Just commit the migrations and re-apply them (`python manage.py migrate`) on the production server each time you deploy.

Comment: Please be advised that if you remove the DB from the repository and push — it will be removed at the server-side.

Comment: So rather than remove from the repository, I should ignore it on my local side and server side right?

Comment: yes. also u should use the mysql server that pythonanywhere gives you for free, instead of sqlite